# Join multiple records on single record

Tags: mysql, sql, join, jdbc

I have this table (lineup):

```
ownerId (pk)
slot1 (fk heroId)
slot2 (fk heroId)
slot3 (fk heroId)
slot4 (fk heroId)
slot5 (fk heroId)
```

Now I need to retrieve the records from table (heroes) corresponding to the slots.

```
heroId (pk)
ownerId (fk)
templateId (fk)
...
```

And join this with the table (herotemplates).

```
templateId (pk)
...
```

So I came up with the following query:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM lineup " +
"JOIN heroes AS slot1hero ON slot1hero.heroId = lineup.slot1 " +
"JOIN herotemplates AS slot1template ON slot1hero.templateId = slot1template.templateId " +

"JOIN heroes AS slot2hero ON slot2hero.heroId = lineup.slot2 " +
"JOIN herotemplates AS slot2template ON slot2hero.templateId = slot2template.templateId " +

"JOIN heroes AS slot3hero ON slot3hero.heroId = lineup.slot3 " +
"JOIN herotemplates AS slot3template ON slot3hero.templateId = slot3template.templateId " +

"JOIN heroes AS slot4hero ON slot4hero.heroId = lineup.slot4 " +
"JOIN herotemplates AS slot4template ON slot4hero.templateId = slot4template.templateId " +

"JOIN heroes AS slot5hero ON slot5hero.heroId = lineup.slot5 " +
"JOIN herotemplates AS slot5template ON slot5hero.templateId = slot5template.templateId " +

"WHERE lineup.ownerId = " + ownerId;
```

However, this returns an empty result. I highly suspect it's the query since I am not very experienced with complicated joins. Any idea what could be wrong with it?

I could fix this by normalizing lineup but I'm never going to use more ore less then 5 slots. I can also split into multiple queries but I'd rather query the database a single time and close the connection asap.

Comment: Assuming the slots are nullable you probably want `OUTER` joins, rather than `INNER` (when you just specify `JOIN` then it is an `INNER JOIN`). So it should be `... FROM lineup LEFT JOIN heroes AS slot1hero ON slot1hero.heroId = lineup.slot1 LEFT JOIN herotemplates AS slot1template ON slot1hero.templateId = slot1template.templateId ...` etc.

Comment: Give some sample data (just for couple of slots) and your output based on that.

Comment: Yes, the slots are nullable. OUTER join gives me an error near `OUTER JOIN ...`. Sure this is implemented in `jdbc` MySQL?

Comment: @Utsav Answer already given. `LEFT JOIN` works like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is difficult to answer without knowing what data is in the table.  You would need a match for each slot since you are using `JOIN`.  I think you may need to be using `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: I have different data in each table. But they are "linked" with `fk`. I basically need to retrieve the actual hero data from the player who owns the hero. But that does not specify the heroes name, race, etc. Those are specified in the template table.

Comment: I think `LEFT JOIN` works. I am getting results back. Let me try to access the result.